# link is not working if i give margin-top exceding -16px

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am using enjoy instagram plugin. I made indicators display none. I have page navigation previous and next which is center aligned.

I wrote link more using a tags below the page navigation not included in plugin. Such that it will redirect to instagram page. Now I would like to make more tag in same line of page nav.
So i gave margin-top -25px such that they are in same line but the link is not working. I created a div for more link and made it to float right,gave `width:60px`, `margin-top:-25px`  , `height:20px`, `display:inline-block`. I have not made any changes in plugin. I wrote more link when plugin code  ends. If any one have solution kindly help me.If any errors in grammar and spelling forgive me.If instamor div is moving to plugindiv then more link is not working.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="insta_block">
  <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar( __( 'Instagram Section', 'aasim' ) ) ) : ?>
        <?php endif; ?> 
<div class="insta_more_link">
<a href="http://instagram.com/chinnireddy" target="_blank">More...</a>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.insta_block{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
   /* background: #ff0;*/
    padding:0 20px;
}
.insta_block .widget-container {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.owl-item .box img{
    width:98%;
}
.owl-pagination{
    display:none;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
    background:#0c4c8c!important;
    opacity:1!important;
    font-weight:600;
}
.insta_more_link {
    font-weight: 600;
    float: right;
    width:60px;
    display: inline-block;
    height:20px;
    margin-top:-25px;

}
.insta_more_link a{
    color:#0c4c8c;
}
```

Comment: I posted my code if any solution help me

Comment: looks fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/c313btrf/ I just moved link to view with `wrapper` div

Comment: i would like to make more link in same line ie where page navigation exits. if you install plugin and upload images you will understand my problem.whwn i made more link to come in same line of prev,nex then the link is not working

Comment: The link is working normally if i try to align in same line where page nav exits then it is not working Though this is silly question but I dont know as i am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

.

```
insta_more_link {
    font-weight: 600;
   /* float: right;*/
    width:60px;
   /* display: inline-block;*/
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;

}
.insta_block{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
   /* background: #ff0;*/
    padding:0 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

By making main  div relative and making my morediv positon absolute I got it